# REACT-NATIVE ERROR: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

Every time I try to the script, it gives me this error. I tried multiple options to solve the problem, but I think I made it worse.

I tried changing the directory, I tried revisiting the code but found nothing. I reinstalled the dependencies, updated the environment and everything but no result.

Here is the code. You will find full error description at the bottom.

```js
// AdminLogin.js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { loginStyles } from './styles/loginStyle.js'; // Import login styles

const AdminLogin = ({ onLogin }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Basic validation: Check if username and password are not empty
    if (username.trim() !== '' && password.trim() !== '') {
      // Successful login, trigger the onLogin callback
      onLogin();
    } else {
      // Display an alert for invalid credentials
      Alert.alert('Invalid Credentials', 'Please enter a valid username and password.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={loginStyles.container}>
      <Text style={loginStyles.header}>Admin Login</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={loginStyles.input}
        placeholder="Username"
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={loginStyles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
       <TouchableOpacity style={loginStyles.loginButton} onPress={handleLogin}>
        <Text style={loginStyles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

```
// loginStyles.js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff', // Background color
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 120,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#007bff',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  loginButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default loginStyle;
```

```plaintext
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in AdminLogin (created by AdminDashboard)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AdminDashboard)
    in AdminDashboard
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in eastt(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in AdminLogin (created by AdminDashboard)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AdminDashboard)
    in AdminDashboard
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in eastt(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `loginStyles` imports as export module but if you look at in loginStyles.js then your modules exported as default and here is a problem.

replace this row

`import { loginStyles } from './styles/loginStyle.js'; // Import login styles`

with

`import loginStyles from './styles/loginStyle.js'; // Import login styles`